# Editing label on different dialog qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I made another window pop up using:

```
SecondDialog object;
object.setModal(true);
object.exec();
```

I added a label on the second dialog using the design form editor. However I would like to use a QString variable from the original dialog to use for that label. Is that possible? And if so how would I do it? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a name for the label in your second dialog. You can do it in the designer's Object inspector (upper right corner by default), left column. Then, create a method

```
void SecondDialog::SetLabelText (QString &text)
{
    ui.myLabel->setText (text);
}
```

Then call it from the first dialog before exec'ing.